# How to resolve package.json not being included in compilation stage?

Tags: node.js, compiler-errors

Here the error in question:

```
Error: Cannot inject the dependency "modCompilerService" at position #3 of "PreAkiModLoader" constructor. Reason:
    File 'C:\**\project\package.json' was not included into executable at compilation stage. Please recompile adding it as asset or script.
    at C:\snapshot\project\node_modules\tsyringe\dist\cjs\dependency-container.js:324:23
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at C:\snapshot\project\node_modules\tsyringe\dist\cjs\dependency-container.js:295:38
    at InternalDependencyContainer.construct (C:\snapshot\project\node_modules\tsyringe\dist\cjs\dependency-container.js:297:11)
    at InternalDependencyContainer.resolveRegistration (C:\snapshot\project\node_modules\tsyringe\dist\cjs\dependency-container.js:166:51)
    at InternalDependencyContainer.resolve (C:\snapshot\project\node_modules\tsyringe\dist\cjs\dependency-container.js:109:33)
    at Program.start (C:\snapshot\project\obj\Program.js:26:52)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\snapshot\project\obj\ide\ReleaseEntry.js:13:9)
    at Module._compile (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1930:22)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
```

I tried to compile a server into an executable. The compiling worked without a problem until I tried to launch the executable and I got the error. I was expecting it to run without this error.

Maybe without resolving the problem, can someone please explain to me what it means?
Also dont hesitate to ask more info, I dont know what I should be showing to make it easier to understand.

Comment: share the scripts you are using.

Comment: The script to compile into an executable ?